# Check if value from one dataframe column exists in another dataframe column using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2,

`df1` has column Name with values like a,b,c etc
`df2` has column Id   with values like a,b

If Name column in `df1` has a match in Id column in `df2`, then we need to have match status as 0. If there is no match then we need to have match status as 1.
I know that I can put `df2` ID column in a collection using collect and then check if Name column in df1 has matching entry.

```
val df1 = Seq(“Rey”, “John”).toDF(“Name”)
val df2 = Seq(“Rey”).toDF(“Id”)

val collect = df2.select("Id").map(r => r.getString(0)).collect.toList
```

something like,

```
    val df3 = 
    df1.withColumn("match_sts",when(df1("Name").isin(collect).then(0).else(1)))

Expected output
+ — — + — -+
|Name|match_sts|
+ — — + — -+
| Rey| 0  |
|John| 1  |
+ — — + — -+
```

But I don't want to use collect here. Is there any alternate approach available.

Comment: May be an example and your own try? Can use spark sql with EXISTS or outer join...

Comment: AS thebluephantom said, please share your attempts or at least examples of your dataframes.

Comment: @thebluephantom shared the approach, I dont want to do a join for df1 with df2

Comment: Indeed, but you need some sort of action to get a so-called side-effect. Aha, but how big is your collect?

Comment: @thebluephantom should be less than 1 lakh rows

Comment: lakh not a term I am aware of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With collect is not what you want, but is a well -known issue for DF col --> list conversion. If not a huge list, then you can do - this works actually, you can also broadcast the inlist:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1 = Seq("Rey", "John", "Donald", "Trump").toDF("Name")
val df2 = Seq("Rey", "Donald").toDF("Id")

val inlist = df2.select("Id").map(r => r.getString(0)).collect.toList

val df3 = df1.withColumn("match_status", when(df1("Name").isin(inlist: _*),1).otherwise(0))
df3.show(false)
```

Even in the classical examples that use the stopwords from a file for filtering output, they do this:

```
val stopWords = stopWordsInput.flatMap(x => x.split(" ")).map(_.trim).collect.toSet
```

and broadcast if too big to the Workers. But I am not sure what 1 lakh is!!!

Another approach is with Spark SQL, relying on Catalyst to optimize SQL when EXISTS is used:

```
import spark.implicits._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df1 = Seq("Rey", "John", "Donald", "Trump").toDF("Name")
val df2 = Seq("Rey", "Donald").toDF("Id") // This can be read from file and split etc.

// Optimizer converts to better physical plan for performance in general
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("searchlist") 
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("inlist")    
val df3 = spark.sql("""SELECT Name, 1 
                     FROM searchlist A
                    WHERE EXISTS (select B.Id from inlist B WHERE B.Id = A.Name )
                                   UNION
                   SELECT Name, 0 
                     FROM searchlist A
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (select B.Id from inlist B WHERE B.Id = A.Name )
                """)
df3.show(false)
```

Comment: @thebluephantom I tried your first approach, but I don't understand something: the OP had said he wanted 1 if there was NO match, but your solution provides 1 if there IS a match, correct?

Comment: It's a while ago, I will look at tonight.

Comment: u could well be right, interchangeable. easy.